# Duplicate zip entry [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class]

Tags: android, proguard

I'm developing a library project which also handles in-app purchases. So I'm including the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file and also the `IabHelper` classes.

The problem is, when the user of my libarary also uses another 3rd party library which uses the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` interface.

Then he gets the *Duplicate zip entry* error:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't write [app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/debug/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [app/build/intermediates/classes/debug(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class]))
```

Adding `-injars libs/mylib.aar(!com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class)` to  his `proguard-rules.txt` doesn't help.

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If yes, how?

Comment: @Palaima I've made another optional version of the library, marked `no-billing`, where all those stuff are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a library with duplicate files, is a bug in gradle, for solve use this in your project build.gradle

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude '.readme'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If library having duplicate files use this in `android{}`

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude '.readme'

}
```